# Memory leak when phone is disconned unexpectedly

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, at-command, gsmcomm

What causes leaking the memory when a phone/GSM module is disconnected unexpectedly, although there are no tasks are being carried out. And How do I handle it. In my application the phone is connected via data cable and gsmcomm library/AT-COMMANDS. I have handled the opening and closing of the connection when the user connects or disconnects the phone using connect/disconnect buttons provided and the application works fine. But if the phone is disconnected unexpectedly (for example user unplugs the data cable) without clicking the disconnect button the size of the application increases on RAM. I understand the connection remained open but no tasks are being carried out. How do I handle this in my application.

Here is the code for connecting and disconnecting the phone/gsm module of the phone. GsmCommMain comes from GSMComm library for connecting the GSM module of the phone.

**Code to connect phone**

```
// pohone connect
#region
 try
 {
   Comm_Port = Convert.ToInt16(capdeviceid.ToString().Substring(3));
   Comm_BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(MaxBaudRate.ToString());
   Comm_TimeOut = Convert.ToInt32(timeoutsec.ToString());
  }
 catch (Exception)
  {
   MessageBox.Show("Error Converting COM Port Settings Values", "Check COM Port Values", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

   MessageBox.Show("Please Redetect the Phone or the phone is already connected.");
   return;
   }

 comm = new GsmCommMain(Comm_Port, Comm_BaudRate, Comm_TimeOut);

 try
   {

    comm.Open();
    if (comm.IsConnected())
      {

       //pictureBox3.Image = imageList1.Images[1];

        MessageBox.Show("Connected Successfully To GSM Phone / Modem...!!!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        PhoneConnectionLabel.Text = captionObj + " Connected";
        this.Text = "From  " + captionObj.ToString();
         sendSMSToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;

         disconnectToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = true;

       }
     }
catch (Exception E2)
      {

       MessageBox.Show(E2.Message);
       MessageBox.Show("Error While Connecting To GSM Phone / Modem", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                //dataGridView3.ClearSelection();

         }
#endregion
```

**Code to disconnect phone**

```
try
   {
    if (!comm.IsConnected())
      {
      MessageBox.Show("No Phone Connected", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
       return;
       }
     else
       {
        comm.Close();
        this.Text = "Form1";
         PhoneConnectionLabel.Text = "No Phone Connected";
         sendSMSToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
         disconnectToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
          }
     }

catch (Exception No_Conn)
    {
     MessageBox.Show("No Phone Connected!!\r\n\n" + No_Conn, "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
     }
```

Comment: We're not really a site for *Here's a really vague description of a problem, with no code to reproduce it. Can you speculate wildly on what might be causing it?* type questions. If you don't understand why, try calling your auto repair shop and saying *My car is making a funny noise when I drive. It's blue, and has four tires and a steering wheel. What's wrong?* and see if you get an answer.

Comment: I think the question is simple and clear about memory leakage when connection remains unclosed. I have clearly mentioned that when phone is connected and disconnected using buttons the connections are closed and there is no problem. I do not think the code is necessary for it.

Comment: So do the people who write the thousands of questions that are downvoted and closed every day. But suit yourself.

Comment: Sir thank you for your interest in helping me. I have update the code for connecting and disconnecting the phone gsm module. I also have updated the body of my question. I really appreciate if help me if you figure out the error. Thank you.

Comment: I have mentioned about GSMComm library. I am using GsmComm.GsmCommunication